# Using UNICODE character values in C++

Tags: c++, unicode

How do you use unicode in C++ ?
Im aware of `wchar_t` and `wchar_t*` but I want to know how you can assign value using only Unicode Values, similar to the way a character can be assigned by equating the variable to the ASCII value:

```
char a = 92;
```

Im uysing the MinGW compiler, if it makes a difference.

Comment: C++11 supports unicode literals and types. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly the same way:

```
wchar_t a = 97;
wchar_t xi = 0x03be; // ξ
```

Comment: According to this document, http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf,
superscript(2) has the number 2071. What is this in integers?
Converting it from hexadecimal to int still makes it crash

Comment: @viraj at the risk of being called perfectionist, an `int` tells us that it is a number without fractional part. However what you might be talking about is base10 numbers, converting from hexadecimal (base16) to base10.

Comment: @viraj The numbers in that document are hexadecimal, so just prefix them with a `0x`, e.g. `0x2071` (which is a superscripted `i`, and not a `2`).

Comment: 0x2072 and onwards just display a round square. 0x2071 works and shows a superscript i.

Comment: Im using a Win32 static control to display unicode characters.

Answer (score 10):

It can be as simple as:

```
wchar_t a=L'a';
wchar_t hello_world[]=L"Hello World";

// Or if you really want it to be (old school) C++ and not C

std::wstring s(L"Hello World");

// Or if you want to (be bleeding edge and) use C++11

std::u16string s16(u"Hello World");
std::u32string s32(U"Hello World for the ∞ᵗʰ time");
```